# service docker start -> /sbin/service: fork: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: docker, rhel7

I have Docker CE running in OpenStack cloud instance RHEL 7.5. The instance was stopped a few days ago (don't know how/why). I restarted it and it seemed to contain everything I had placed there before.

When I tried to start Docker I got this after about 1 minute:

```
# service docker start
/sbin/service: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

`top` shows that there is plenty of memory:

```
KiB Mem :  8174548 total,  7994528 free,   114168 used,    65852 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  7877828 avail Mem
```

Next I uninstalled docker and removed `/var/lib/docker` and `/etc/docker` directories. I reinstalled it with:

```
yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

and I'm still getting the same error. I also rebooted but it does not help. Docker version is this:

```
# docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.6
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        481bc77156
 Built:             Sat May  4 02:34:58 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**Edit:**

```
# uname -r
3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64

# virt-what
kvm
```

Comment: First thing I would recommend is that you update the system (and reboot into the new kernel). It's not really reasonable to try to debug a problem that may be with an out of date kernel. At least not unless you're paying a very large amount of money for such support.

Comment: I did `yum update` and rebooted. It did not change the kernel version reported by `uname -r` nor fixed the problem with Docker.

Comment: Eh? Did you accidentally stick your system on 7.5? It should have updated you to 7.6.

Comment: Probably yes. I stopped fighting with the old instance, started a new cloud instance and everything works there now. I had some problems earlier starting a new instance, that's why I needed to get this working.